# No Compatible APKs found for the device

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I was testing the new version of Ionic framework with Capacitor as I tried to build and run my app on emulator and my device I faced this error without success in installing app

> No Compatible APKs found for the device.
>   [image]

after lots of search and struggling to fix this and lots of fails, as I was talking to one of my friends about it I realised maybe this is related to build configuration.

as I could not find similar anywhere I decided to share the answer here maybe helps and save someone time.

Answer (score 1):

No Compatible APKs found for the device.

This error appears to your Build Output when android studio cannot find the related APK file generated, so by a simple change in your buid configuration you can fix this, in my case I fixed the problem like this:
thorugh this section select:

> Edit Configuration

[image]

[image]

default Deploy option under Installation option is set to

> APK from app bundle

[image]

by changing it to

> Default APK

[image]

you'll be able to build and run your app successfully.

I hope it help you to run your shiny app asap ;p